# Is there a way to display test results from an XML file in Azure Dashboards?

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to display test results  from an XML file in Azure Dashboards. Test results are saved to an XML file on the build machine when a pipeline runs, I need to import these into an Azure dashboard...is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a widget that can directly display test results from XML files.

There is a workaround you can refer to:

1. You can create a pipeline and use task "Publish Test Results" to publish the test results of the XML file.
   [image]
2. Add a widget called "Test Results Trend" to Dashboards.
   [image]

Configure the **Build pipeline** as the pipeline you just published the test result.
[image]

Then you can see the report like this one:

[image]