# How to publish the detailedLogs.xml test result file?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to retrieve the test results and followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72879734/8397835) for the retrieval process. I'm able to retrieve the `junit.xml` file captured in the screenshot but the `detailedLogs.xml` file is apparently not retrievable (not found)? Is it because of the `/./` in the path?

[image: xml test results]

> 2023-09-12T02:06:37.0498037Z ##[warning]No test result files matching **/qa-automation/TestResults/./CurrentReport/Logs/detailedLogs.xml were found.

Do note that the junit.xml file says there was an error but that's part of the test case pass/fail process, so I didn't think it would have anything to do with this. Because the test result is something about one of the test cases authentication according to the junit.xml file:

> System.Exception : Valid login credentials QualityAssuranceUserName/QualityAssurancePassword missing. Check either local secrets file or app configuration">   at selenium.Resources.Commands.GetTestDataVariables.GetValidLoginCredentials(String application)

[image: testresult]